# Android Device Screen Size compared to emulator

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm new to android and now I'm calculating some of the coordinates based on the screen size of my emulator in android studio, whose width is 1080. Can I assume that other devices also have this size or close to 1080?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot assume that any two Android devices will have the same or similar screen dimensions, even newer phones, for example:

Pixel XL: 1440 x 2560
Pixel: 1080 x 1920

You should look at this: https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

It will introduce you to the techniques used to have items be the same size regardless of screen dimensions or pixel density.